# Cordova build error - Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, cordova

I can't solve this ...
if anyone knows how to solve it please tell me
I can't speak English well :/

> 9 errors

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3 mins 47.964 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
  F:\Android\HelloAndroid\platforms\android\src\net\super\helloandroid\MainActivity.java:20: error:  expected
  package net.super.helloandroid;
          ^
  F:\Android\HelloAndroid\platforms\android\src\net\super\helloandroid\MainActivity.java:20: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  package net.super.helloandroid;
               ^
  F:\Android\HelloAndroid\platforms\android\src\net\super\helloandroid\MainActivity.java:20: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  package net.super.helloandroid;
                ^
  F:\Android\HelloAndroid\platforms\android\build\generated\source\r\debug\net\super\helloandroid\R.java:8: error:  expected
  package net.super.helloandroid;
          ^
  F:\Android\HelloAndroid\platforms\android\build\generated\source\r\debug\net\super\helloandroid\R.java:8: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  package net.super.helloandroid;
               ^
  F:\Android\HelloAndroid\platforms\android\build\generated\source\r\debug\net\super\helloandroid\R.java:8: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  package net.super.helloandroid;
                ^
  F:\Android\HelloAndroid\platforms\android\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\net\super\helloandroid\BuildConfig.java:4: error:  expected
  package net.super.helloandroid;
          ^
  F:\Android\HelloAndroid\platforms\android\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\net\super\helloandroid\BuildConfig.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  package net.super.helloandroid;
               ^
  F:\Android\HelloAndroid\platforms\android\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\net\super\helloandroid\BuildConfig.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  package net.super.helloandroid;
                ^
  9 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Java and android SDK

Set Environment variables

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `JAVA_HOME` and `ANDROID_SDK` variables before the build.